# Good lightweight library for HTTP POST/GET for C?

Tags: c, http, sockets, winsock

I'm planning of creating a Last.FM scrobbler plugin for a music player in Windows. [Last.FM submissions API](http://www.last.fm/api/submissions) relays on HTTP/1.1 GET and POST.

I've never done Internet oriented programming and I've still to know about the HTTP protocol but I'd like to start playing around with it sending and getting some data. I've looked at the Winsock interface but I don't know if it would be better to use any easier thing.

Do anyone of you know how could I do it? What could I use?

If so, could you point me to a tutorial too?

If it's a library it would be good that I can link statically to it, I would want to supply only the DLL of the plugin.

Comment: Two single-header alternatives here: 1) https://github.com/lammertb/libhttp, 2) https://github.com/mattiasgustavsson/libs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows comes with [WinHttp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/winhttp-start-page), which does support GET and POST.

Comment: Thank very much! Right now I'm thinking about using WinHTTP or libcurl.

Answer (score 17):

[LibCurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) is one of the most widely used and most portable.

Comment: Thank you very much! Defining HTTP_ONLY becomes a lightweight alternative to have in mind (200KB).

Comment: They also have some alternatives to libcurl on their pages: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/competitors.html

Comment: I don't think it qualifies as lightweight

Answer (score 4):

[libghttp](http://linux.maruhn.com/sec/libghttp.html) is pretty lightweight.

Im unsure if it will compile cleanly on win32 though.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't compile easily on win32 but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread but in case this helps anyone else:

Use libCurl http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simplepost.html

This is the easiest way I've found of doing a quick http post or get